# What does the `*` after the `function` keyword mean while declaring a javascript function

Tags: javascript

While looking at the [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) library, I came across the following code:

```
var FS = require("q-io/fs");
var readJsonPromise = Q.async(function *(path) {
    return JSON.parse(yield FS.read(path));
});
```

What is the significance of `*` after the `function` keyword?

Comment: C'mon... ["javascript function asterisk"](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+function+asterisk)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart My searches for `javascript function *` returned those damned w3schools links. I didn't think of trying other search alternatives like `function asterisk`.

Comment: FYI `*` is a [search operator](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/136861?hl=en&ref_topic=3081620).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I know, but escaping * didn't help either. I submitted a question close request. But the JS tag community is super efficient! as the question was closed by the time I requested..

Comment: @HarishShetty The human brain actually needs to see multiple ways that questions are asked an answered, in order to make sense from them.  I actually learned a lot by looking at your question and the docs after.